# How can I parse a large JSON file with repeating values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, stream, jsonstream

I am parsing a large JSON file using JSON stream. This works but it returns the file line by line. So when I try and restructure the data I can only get the data that is not repeating.

For example, this is the structure:

```
{
    "Test": {
        "id": 3454534344334554345434,
        "details": {
            "text": "78679786787"
        },
        "content": {
            "text": 567566767656776
        },
        "content": {
            "text": 567566767656776
        },
        "content": {
            "text": 567566767656776
        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to get `Test.id` or `Test.details.id` but I can only get the First `Test.content` per line.

I've tried to set in an array but this still gets only the first line of `Test.content`.

Is there another way to transform a large file other than using JSONStream?

Parsing code:

```
var getStream = function () {
    let stream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, '../test.json'), {
            encoding: 'utf8'
        }),
        parser = JSONStream.parse('*.Test')
    return stream.pipe(parser);
};

getStream()
    .pipe(es.mapSync(function (data) {
        let dataObj = []
        dataObj.push(data)
        processData(dataObj)
    }))


function processData(d) {
    let js = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(d))
    console.log(js)
    // js.forEach(function (value, index) {
    //     Object.keys(value).forEach(function (v, i) {});

    // })
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200371/discussion-on-question-by-blulotus-how-can-i-parse-a-large-json-file-with-repeat).